# Using multer in middleware and passing the file object to the next

Tags: node.js

I am using multer function and expect to access the file object in the next middleware. In the first case I succeed and in the second one I fail and I am wondering why

/*The below code works perfectly req.file object is printed successfully */

```
app.post('/api/v1/tasks/insertproduct', multerUpload.single('productImage'),(req,res,next) => {
console.log(req.file);
});
```

/*However the following code , I dont have any luck to get the file object printed */

```
CloudinaryUpload = (req,res,next) => {
    console.log('Iam in cloudinary middleware');
    console.log('REQ: ' + req.file)

    }

app.post('/api/v1/tasks/insertproduct', multerUpload.single('productImage'),CloudinaryUpload);
```